# Data Scraping Google Sheets Formula N/a and Incomplete

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Right now I am scraping certain Productinformation from bol.com.

The product data is getting scraped. But for each 30 products, about 5 are either scraping incomplete data, for instance the EAN is missing, while its in the same content block as normal or it just gives N/A. While there is information.

Any tips?

Ps. This is my current formula: =importxml(C27;"//*[@id='mainContent']/div/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/dl")

C27 is the URL. (https://www.bol.com/nl/nl/p/adroitgoods-hondenriem-180-cm-hondenlijn-looplijn-hondenlijn-reflecterend-rood-lange-lijn-hond/9300000101425619/)

It should import the following product information:

EAN
Kleur
Materiaal
Maat
Reflecterend
Speciaal voor hardlopen
Type uitlaatriem
Verpakkingsinhoud

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(IMPORTxML(A1, "//dl[@class='specs__list']/div")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Though it doesnt load in the data so it only loads in EAN
Kleur
Materiaal
Maat
Reflecterend
Speciaal voor hardlopen
Type uitlaatriem
Verpakkingsinhoud
Type dier
Product lengte
Product breedte
Product hoogte
Gewicht
Grootte honden/kattenras
Product gewicht
Set met halsband
Verpakking breedte
Verpakking hoogte
Verpakking lengte
Categorieën
Type uitlaatriem
Kleur
Merk
Materiaal

and not the data itself

Comment: Ah, It has the same issues. Some do load in and some don't. I think this has to do with the data being dynamically loaded in through json or js.